# Notify SIM content change to ME

Tags: sim-card, sim-toolkit

If I modify the content of USIM/SIM EFs programmatically (using a SIMToolkit applet for example), then can the USIM/SIM force the ME to update its state based on the new content of the SIM EFs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `REFRESH` proactive command. It does exactly what you need.

Good luck with your project!